# Download Windows XP SP3 iso

Tags: windows-xp, boot-camp, service-pack

I got a license for Windows XP Pro here and wanted to install this on my Mac as a Bootcamp System but the Disc is only SP1 so it crashes on installation with a BSOD stating IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. This is not really surprising as Bootcamp states you need SP3 to install.

So I'm looking for a legal download source of a Windows XP Pro SP3 Installation disc that I can use with my product key from the SP1 disc or a possibility of creating a SP3 disc myself sourcing from my SP1 disc.

Comment: How about this? http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=25129

Comment: I'll have a look thanks, but it looks like this is only the SP3 update as a CD-iso (at least there's no sign of this beeing the Home or Pro edition) wich wouldn't get me far since I never get to finish the Windows-Install with my disc so I can't run any update :/

Comment: SP CD's work on both home and pro. See my answer below for how to slipstream that SP CD ISO into a Windows XP disk.

Comment: Yep, but as said before I can't install in the first place so the SP CD is useless, I'm currently trying to slipstream SP3 into my SP1 CD :)

Comment: Microsoft has removed the link to download windows XP. But still in case you need it. You can download ISO of Windows XP  from https://offlineinstallersofts.com/windows-xp-sp3-iso-free-download-full-version.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you already have a legal Windows XP disk (or ISO image) you can slipstream a service pack into a new CD image.

Here is a guide on how you can build a new Windows XP installation CD with SP3 already on it:
http://lifehacker.com/386526/slipstream-service-pack-3-into-your-windows-xp-installation-cd

Service packs are cumulative, so it's sufficient to slipstream SP3. You don't need to include SP1 and SP2 first.

Edit: This guide is a little more simple, http://winsupersite.com/windows-xp/slipstreaming-windows-xp-service-pack-3-sp3

Comment: Brilliant! Wish I could give more than one upvote!

Comment: Worked great, Bootcamp is up and running, thanks :)